# Mutate by column position using case_when

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following dataframe in R

```
data <- structure(list(Category = c("Food", "Alcoholic B&T", "Clothing", 
"Housing", "Furnishings", "Health", "Transport", "Communication", 
"Recreation", "Education", "Hotels", "Misc", "All Items"), Weight = c(16.4, 
12.6, 3, 28.4, 5.5, 2, 14.3, 3.8, 3.6, 3.6, 1.4, 5.4, 100), `Apr 2022 (A)` = c(5.7, 
4.5, -2, 1.7, 7.7, 1.7, 18.9, -1.1, 4.4, 3.1, 9.3, 0.5, 5.6), 
    `May 2022 (F)` = c(7, 4.8, -1.6, 1.7, 7.8, 1.7, 19.3, -0.7, 
    4.7, 3.1, 9.1, 0.3, 6), `Jun 2022 (F)` = c(7.4, 5, -1.4, 
    1.7, 7.3, 1.8, 18.9, -0.2, 4.6, 3.1, 9.3, 0.5, 6.1), `Jul 2022 (F)` = c(7.7, 
    4.7, -1.5, 3.1, 7.4, 1.8, 18.4, -0.4, 4.2, 3.1, 8.8, 0.7, 
    6.4)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I would like to `mutate` a new column using `case_when` which prints an up arrow if column 6 is larger than column 3, a down arrow if column 6 is smaller than column 3, or a side-arrow if column 6 and 3 are equal. I have done it in this way in the past, however I'm getting an error now. Is there a better way to do this?

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
mutate(Trend = case_when(.[,6] == .[,3] ~ "\U279E", 
                              .[,6] > .[,3] ~ "\U2B08", TRUE ~ "\U2B0A"))
```

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `Trend = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `case_when()`:
! `.[, 6] == .[, 3]` must be a vector with type <logical>.
Instead, it has type <logical[,1]>.
```

Comment: I don't get this error, your approach is working fine. I'm on dplyr 1.0.7.

Comment: @TimTeaFan I can reproduce this error using `dplyr 1.1.0`.

Comment: Note that in `dplyr 1.1.0`, it's being recommended to use `.default` instead of `TRUE` for remaining values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general I would avoid this pattern of picking by position but you cloud use `[[` to make you code work:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  mutate(Trend = case_when(
    .[[6]] == .[[3]] ~ "\U279E",
    .[[6]] > .[[3]] ~ "\U2B08", 
    TRUE ~ "\U2B0A"
  ))
#> # A tibble: 13 × 7
#>    Category      Weight `Apr 2022 (A)` `May 2022 (F)` Jun 2022 (…¹ Jul 2…² Trend
#>    <chr>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>
#>  1 Food            16.4            5.7            7            7.4     7.7 ⬈    
#>  2 Alcoholic B&T   12.6            4.5            4.8          5       4.7 ⬈    
#>  3 Clothing         3             -2             -1.6         -1.4    -1.5 ⬈    
#>  4 Housing         28.4            1.7            1.7          1.7     3.1 ⬈    
#>  5 Furnishings      5.5            7.7            7.8          7.3     7.4 ⬊    
#>  6 Health           2              1.7            1.7          1.8     1.8 ⬈    
#>  7 Transport       14.3           18.9           19.3         18.9    18.4 ⬊    
#>  8 Communication    3.8           -1.1           -0.7         -0.2    -0.4 ⬈    
#>  9 Recreation       3.6            4.4            4.7          4.6     4.2 ⬊    
#> 10 Education        3.6            3.1            3.1          3.1     3.1 ➞    
#> 11 Hotels           1.4            9.3            9.1          9.3     8.8 ⬊    
#> 12 Misc             5.4            0.5            0.3          0.5     0.7 ⬈    
#> 13 All Items      100              5.6            6            6.1     6.4 ⬈    
#> # … with abbreviated variable names ¹​`Jun 2022 (F)`, ²​`Jul 2022 (F)`
```

Answer (score 2):

Like @TimTeaFan,  I can't reproduce this error.  I'm using `dplyr` 1.0.10.

That said, here's a function-based solution that avoids the issue of using column indices and which, in my opinion at least, leads to more understandable code...

```
makeTrend <- function(col1, col2) {
  case_when({{col1}} == {{col2}} ~ "\U279E", 
            {{col1}} > {{col2}} ~ "\U2B08", 
            TRUE ~ "\U2B0A")
}

data %>% mutate(Trend=makeTrend(`Jul 2022 (F)`, `Apr 2022 (A)`))
# A tibble: 13 × 7
   Category      Weight `Apr 2022 (A)` `May 2022 (F)` `Jun 2022 (F)` `Jul 2022 (F)` Trend
   <chr>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl> <chr>
 1 Food            16.4            5.7            7              7.4            7.7 ⬈    
 2 Alcoholic B&T   12.6            4.5            4.8            5              4.7 ⬈    
 3 Clothing         3             -2             -1.6           -1.4           -1.5 ⬈    
 4 Housing         28.4            1.7            1.7            1.7            3.1 ⬈    
 5 Furnishings      5.5            7.7            7.8            7.3            7.4 ⬊    
 6 Health           2              1.7            1.7            1.8            1.8 ⬈    
 7 Transport       14.3           18.9           19.3           18.9           18.4 ⬊    
 8 Communication    3.8           -1.1           -0.7           -0.2           -0.4 ⬈    
 9 Recreation       3.6            4.4            4.7            4.6            4.2 ⬊    
10 Education        3.6            3.1            3.1            3.1            3.1 ➞    
11 Hotels           1.4            9.3            9.1            9.3            8.8 ⬊    
12 Misc             5.4            0.5            0.3            0.5            0.7 ⬈    
13 All Items      100              5.6            6              6.1            6.4 ⬈
```

Comment: Not sure why you *can't* reproduce the error because the error message makes perfect sense: subsetting a tibble (unlike a data.frame!) does not discard dimensions. `.[, i]` is not a vector. Maybe ‘dplyr’ had a regression somewhere around version 1.0.x that got fixed subsequently.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: True, good point, it should throw an error.